# Does a lack of aching means i've lost weight?

Tags: weight-loss, muscle-soreness

I go on 30 minute walks every day during work (apart from weekends) and every night at home i do 100 situps (including on weekends).

in the begining during my walks my calves would ache like hell and with the sit ups i struggled past 50 (being very difficult to sit up each time but still pushing though), there's no scales at home for me to check and i don't look as if i lost any weight (i have a but of a gut on me) however i can easily walk the 30 minutes and could keep going if it wasn't for the fact i was doing it during work hours and 100 pushups aren't all that hard having just closed my eyes and counted to one hundred and not feeling nearly as drained as i once thought.

I am wondering, does the fact i no longer feel any pain to these mean i have lost weight or is it just my body has adapted to the pain and i may not actually be loosing any weight from this anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know if you've lost weight is to actually measure your weight.  The fact that you're no longer experiencing pain does not equate to weight loss.  As you've said, it simply means that your body is adapting to the exercise stress it has been under.  Keep up the good work, and you will lose weight.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate further on @rrirower, I think that it means that your body is no longer stressed as intensely as it was when you begun doing the exercise. You've probably gained or 'toned' muscle to help you with your routine. Adding more muscle mass does tend to add a little weight, but you will definitely lose some body fat as well.

The lack of soreness probably means you've gained muscle mass, I only imagine you've lost a bit of body fat doing those exercises.

**In short. If your weight has been stagnant before you started your workouts, then these exercise will likely take off a few pounds.**

I had an experience similar to yours. I started a routine when I was morbidly obese. After a few years of dedicated exercise, I weighed the same as I always have but my body is thinner and muscular.

Perhaps weight loss won't always be your goal if you want to be healthier.